# How does memory work in declaration of structure which uses self-referential structure pointer in C/C++?

Tags: c++, pointers, structure, self-reference

In declaration of structure in C/C++, we have to use a self-referential structure pointer instead of a structure itself.

*// compile error*

```
struct stack {
    int overflow;
    stack p;
}
```

```
struct stack {
    int overflow;
    stack* p;
}
```

One brings about the error but the other doesn't under the same condition(*declaration*)
I'm curious about the operation of memory areas when use `stack* p;` during the declaration and how to make it possible.

Comment: To understand the difference, maybe try to think about the size (in bytes) that an instance
of the 'stack' struct would have in memory
 for the 2 different cases.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This

```
struct stack {
    int overflow;
    stack p;
}
```

Tries to contains itself , so how big should it be? With one copy of itself it would look line this

```
 int ov;
 {
     int ov;
     stack p;
 }
```

but that stack p needs to be expanded - so we get

```
 int ov;
 {
     int ov;
    {
         int ov;
         stack p;
    }
 }
```

but that stack p needs to be expanded - so we get

```
 int ov;
 {
     int ov;
    {
         int ov;
         {
             int ov;
             stack p;
          }
    }
 }
```

but that stack p needs to be expanded - so we get ...... forever.

Look at another way, how many int overflows should the struct contain?

The pointer one works like this

```
  int overflow;
  stack *p;
```

The end. The struct is of a well defined size an integer and a pointer